# ACCESS - How can I set the Split Form Size property and make it stay constant?

Tags: forms, ms-access, split, size

I have been pulling my hair on this one; I am sure the answer is very simple but I do not know how to fix it!

I have a contact split form, on which I have the datasheet on the left side, and the text fields on the right. I would like to set the size of the right field to be 6.5". By going into Layout, I can modify by either dragging the split bar, or by changing the Split Form Side property to 6.5". Great !

[Form View After Layout modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXmHw.jpg)

[Property Sheet under Layout Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDh0.jpg)

Nice, amazing;

Now I go back under design view, and when I try to go back into Form view, this is what happen:

[Form View after Design View modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOivy.jpg)

Ok, what the ... is this ? My Datasheet view on the left side is squished, and the text fields on the right have more room than I do in my apartment. It looks like the dividing line in between is set to center itself; Well, I then go back to the Design View to check out what is happening, and this is what the Property Sheet states:

[Design View and Property Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyUlD.jpg)

So ok, the Split Form Size is still at 6.5"; I guess it is good!

What about Layout View now:

[Layout View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysusc.jpg)

Split Form Size = Auto ???

Why ? How can I make this stay constant? I know I could probably use some VBA, but really? Isn't there another solution? Does it simply come from another property I have set wrong? My window is not set on "Pop Up" by the way.

Let me know! Hopefully it is something easy!

Comment: SplitFormSize property is determined by whatever is set by user in Form view by grab and drag splitter bar. I avoid Split form if I need to manage form with code. I also seldom use Layout View and usually disable it.

Comment: However, LayoutView does not switch SplitFormSize property to Auto for me. Holds whatever was set by moving splitter bar.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you June7;

I fixed it by reading what was on page 2 of this pdf : [PDF-form-create-split](http://informationtechnology.sienaheights.edu/uploads/6/5/6/7/6567343/form-create-split.pdf)

Basically, I had the **property Save Splitter Bar Position = No while it should have been on Yes.**; it was a mistake because I thought that setting it to No, will mean that no matter what the user would set the splitter bar at, will not be saved, and will go back to the value I saved. However, it does not matter because I set the property Split Form Splitter Bar = No, meaning that the User would not be able to access the splitter bar, hence not being able to change it!

Sometimes, the fix is so simple!